# pandas speed up creation of columns from column of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, performance, pandas

I have an original dataset with informations stored as a list of dict, in a column (this is a mongodb extract). This is the column :

```
[{u'domain_id': ObjectId('A'),  u'p': 1}, 
{u'domain_id': ObjectId('B'),  u'p': 2},
{u'domain_id': ObjectId('B'),  u'p': 3},
... 
{u'domain_id': ObjectId('CG'),  u'p': 101}]
```

I'm only interested in the first 10 dict ( 'p' value from 1 to 10). The output dataframe should look like this :

```
index |  A  | ... |  B
------------------------
0     |  1  | ... | 2
1     | Nan | ... | Nan
2     | Nan | ... | 3
```

e.g : For each line of my original DataFrame, I create a column for each domain_id, and I associate it with the corresponding 'p' value. I can have the same domain_id for several 'p' value, in this case I only keep the first one (smaller 'p')

Here is my current code, which may be easier to understand :

```
first = True
for i in df.index[:]: # for each line of original Dataframe
    temp_list = df["positions"][i] # this is the column with the list of dict inside
    col_list = []
    data_list = []
    for j in range(10): # get the first 10 values
        try:
            if temp_list[j]["domain_id"] not in col_list: # check if domain_id already exist
                col_list.append(temp_list[j]["domain_id"])
                data_list.append(temp_list[j]["p"])
        except IndexError as e:
            print e
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame([np.transpose(data_list)],columns = col_list) # create a temporary DataFrame for this line of the original DataFrame
    if first:
        df_kw = df_temp
        first = False
    else:
#             pass
        df_kw = pd.concat([df_kw,df_temp], axis=0, ignore_index=True) # concat all the temporary DataFrame : now I have my output Dataframe, with the same number of lines as my original DataFrame.
```

This is all working fine, but it is very very slow as I have 15k lines and end up with 10k columns.

I'm sure (or at least I hope very much) that there is a simpler an faster solution : any advice will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a decent solution : the slow part is the concatenation, so it is way more efficient to first create the dataframe and then update the values.

Create the DataFrame:

```
for i in df.index[:]:
    temp_list = df["positions"][i]
    for j in range(10):
        try:
#             if temp_list[j]["domain_id"] not in col_list:
            col_list.append(temp_list[j]["domain_id"])
        except IndexError as e:
            print e

df_total = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, columns=set(col_list))
```

Update the values :

```
for i in df.index[:]:
    temp_list = df["positions"][i]
    col_list = []
    for j in range(10):
        try:
            if temp_list[j]["domain_id"] not in col_list: # avoid overwriting values
                df_total.loc[i, temp_list[j]["domain_id"]] = temp_list[j]["p"]
                col_list.append(temp_list[j]["domain_id"])
        except IndexError as e:
            print e
```

Creating a 15k x 6k DataFrame took about 6 seconds on my computer, and filling it took 27 seconds.
I killed the former solution after more than 1 hour running, so this is really faster.